# Scrapy to post a formdata and get results from the same url

Tags: python, scrapy, iteration

I'd like to submit a formdata, scrape the result, add +1 to the formdata value and get the next result from the same url and so on.
this code returns only one result:

```
import scrapy

class natigah(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "natiga"
    start_urls = ["https://natega.youm7.com/Home/Result"]


def parse(self, response):
    data = {"seating_no":"1112346"}
    for i in data:
        data[i] = int(data[i])
        while data[i] < 1112356:
            data[i] += 1
            keys_values = data.items()
            formdata = {str(key): str(value) for key, value in keys_values}
            return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
                response,
                formdata=formdata,
                callback=self.after_login
            )
          
def after_login(self, response):
    for product in response.css(".RightSide"):
        yield {
            "name": product.css(".full-result > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2)::text").get(),
            "seat_no": product.css("li.col:nth-child(1) > h1:nth-child(2)::text").get(),
            "Percent": product.css("li.col:nth-child(3) > h1::text").get()
            }
```

I added next_page as following but the result is an infinite loop for the same result when "seating_no":"1112347"

```
    next_page = 'https://natega.youm7.com/Home/Result'
    if next_page is not None:

                yield scrapy.Request(next_page, dont_filter=True)
```

Comment: you are not making any changes in formdata = {"no" : "1"} , for any addtional request you maybe needs to change formdata

Comment: I Have updated the code so formdata now changes but still no progress